# group date_time column into hourly, daily and weekly data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to php and MySql databases
my database consists of date_time(%m-%d-%Y %h:%i:%s) as column1 and count as column2,tablename dataforchart

I wish to group this data into hourly, weekly and hourly data and I couldn't get the desired result as:
week1
date_time                      count
01-17-2017 to 01-24-2017      sum(count)
-----                           ----
-----                           ----

and so on 
it should dynamically group data into weeks starting from any day 
I could only reach up to
SET DATEFIRST 1

```
SELECT CAST(MIN(01-15-2017) AS VARCHAR(20))+' TO '+CAST (MAX(01-21-2017) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DATE,
       SUM(`count`) AS count,
FROM   dataforchart
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK,01-15-2017)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT 01-21-2017)=7
```

SET DATEFIRST 7";

but this couldn't help

Comment: Please keep in mind, use the already  DATETIME from MySql with values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format - it's an international format ISO 8601. In MySQL, there are many built-in functions like `Month()` aso.

Comment: I have tried week() and month() functions but still i couldn't reach the desired output

Comment: it would be  a great help if you could just guide me with usage

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dataforcart 
WHERE(date_time BETWEEN LIKE'01/10/2017%' AND LIKE '01/16/2017%)'");                                                                                                         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  echo $row['date_time'] . "\t" . $row['count']. "\n";
}                                                                                                              is giving me error, **mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**

Comment: To start with, I agree that you should use the built in date and time data types, that way you can do comparisons and searches using the built-in functions. As far as the actual data you're trying to compute, the `DATE_ADD()` function is probably what you'll want here.